# Partial Data deletes using Java SQL Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, db2

Our Java program has to delete large number of records from DB2 tables but it is running out of Transaction logs.

We are working on increasing the logs space but due to internal processes and other things... it will take a week+ to complete.

We are looking for a temporary way to delete a few records at a time instead of deleting all. For e.g When we have 1000 records to delete, we want the program to delete 50 records at a time and then do a commit and proceed for next 50 until all 1000 records deleted. If delete fails after X number of records deletion, it is still fine.

We are using Hibernate.

Requesting your suggestion on how it can be achieved. I'm looking at checking the sqlstate and sqlcode in java even on successful sql execution scenario but my bad, i couldn't find a way.

so like, loop do... while(check sqlcode for completion not true)

We cannot delete from back-end as the deletions are supposed to happen on user requests from java web application and in addition, we also have some table constraints and delete cascades.

Comment: Why not a large single bulk delete instead of all single deletes?

Comment: @M.Deinum, As mentioned, we are running out of transactional log space with single bulk delete.

Comment: It wasn't that apparent imho from your post but alas. If you know the ids which you want to delete then simply chop them up in manageable chunks. Also you state you are using hibernate depending on what you do are you using JQL to delete records or retrieve them and remove them or use SQL to blast them away?

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks for taking interest and answering my query.

This is what we are doing now:
`
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.createSQLquery("delete from schema.table where id=:id").setParameter("id", userinput).executeUpdate;
transaction.commit();`
And apologies if my problem is not clear in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Hibernate but you can change your delete to:

```
delete from (
     select * from schema.table where id=:id fetch first 50 rows only
)
```

Assuming executeUpdate() returns the number of rows deleted you can put this in a loop (pseudocode):

```
... stmt = session.createSQLquery("delete from ( ... fetch first 50 rows only )");
int n = 1
while (n > 0) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    n = stmt.executeUpdate();
    transaction.commit();    
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the semantics so you might have to move the stmt = ... inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, really appreciate it. 

Yes executeUpdate will return number of rows updated or deleted.